# [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata

Tags: boot

When I try to install ubuntu it comes up with a black screen that reads:[Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x52 (or later). Then the screen freezes and I cannot type anything like other guides say. Does anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: In install case try newer installation ISO or update CPU microcode from BIOS.